# Acceleromter service does not work on Android TV Box

Tags: android, service, accelerometer

I am developing an application which run Accelerometer services in background. Inside this Accelerometer service i fetch data from server. But the app works fine on Mobile Phone but it does not work on Android TV Box.
Here is the code

```
 public class AccelerometerService extends Service implements    
 SensorEventListener
  {
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)   
 {
  // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
  }

boolean loading_data=false;

public void onCreate()  
    {

screenLock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
         PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");

//((( Hanlder Class RUN after 1 Seocond. Update Time/Date  )))))
    final Handler someHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
      someHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
  {
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       @Override
      public void run()
      {
         someHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);

      //     total_sec_count=obj.Get_Count_Val();

        // total_sec_count+=2;

         //obj.Set_Screen_count(total_sec_count);

        // showtoast("ddd = "+total_sec_count);
        // Log.e("count val = ",""+total_sec_count);


        // showtoast(("lat/long = "+SingletonClass.getInstance().Get_Latitude()+":"+SingletonClass.getInstance().Get_Longitude()));
      }
  }, 2000);
```

}

```
public void TunrOnWifi() 
 {
   WifiManager wifiManager =    
(WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
   showtoast("Wifi Tunred On");
  }

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
 {


if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) +
                Math.pow(y, 2) +
                Math.pow(z, 2)) - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
       /// Log.e("mySensor", "Acceleration is " + acceleration + "m/s^2");

        if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) 
        {
            mLastShakeTime = curTime;
            Log.e("this", "FALL DETECTED");

        }

        if(networkobj.Check_Network_Status()==false)
        TunrOnWifi();

        if(!db.Get_User_Info().get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("NoEmail"))
        {

             if(loading_data==false)
             {
                 Log.e("Loading DATA STARTED......",""+status+" "+email);

                loading_data=true;
                SigninAccount();
             }
        }

       //  Log.e("Accelertion is = ",""+acceleration + "m/s^2");
        if(db.GetAppStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("approved"))
        {
            //Log.e("APP IS Approved = ",""+acceleration + "m/s^2"+" "+email);
        }
        else
        {
            //Log.e("APP is not Approved = ",""+acceleration + "m/s^2 "+email);

            //if(!db.Get_User_Info().get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("NoEmail"))
              Move_App_Back_to_ForeGround();

        }



    }
}
```

}//EOF Onsensor changed

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e("this", "Start Detecting");
    SM = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mySensor = SM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    SM.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

```
//here u should make your service foreground so it will keep working even if app closed


return Service.START_STICKY;
```

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

```
public void showtoast(String str)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//((( Move App To Screen from Background ))))
public void Move_App_Back_to_ForeGround()
{
    boolean foregroud=false;
    try
    {
     foregroud = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(getApplicationContext()).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {   e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(!foregroud)
    {
    //Open Activity IF it is in Background...
    Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
    it.setComponent(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(),LoginActivity.class.getName()));        
    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);


    }
}

class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
        return isAppOnForeground(context);
      }

      private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
          return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
          if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }


public void SigninAccount()
{   
    ArrayList<String>data=new ArrayList<String>();
    data=db.Get_User_Info();
    name=db.Get_User_Info().get(1);
    password=db.Get_User_Info().get(2);
    email=db.Get_User_Info().get(3);


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() 
        {
            String message="Nothing happend";
         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {

          InputStream is=null;
          String result=null;
           ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));






    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();//("http://employeetrackersystem.comule.com/signin.php");/
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pir.alphasols.com/Android_SmartTV_App/login_in_background.php");          
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        //Now get the response of the Registeration of new User
        try {

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = is;//entity.getContent();
                String result1= convertStreamToString(instream); //calling function

               // Log.e("result",""+result1.toString());


               JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result1);

                name=arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("1");                   
                status=arr.getJSONObject(1).getString("1");

                message=name;               
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
              message="Error occured";//: "+e.toString();
        }  


    }
     catch(Exception e)
    {
         message="Error occured";
    }

    return null;

   } protected void onPostExecute(String token) 

   {
             // showtoast("message = "+message);
       loading_data=false;

      if( !(message.equalsIgnoreCase("no_email")))
      {

      if(!(message.equalsIgnoreCase("Error occured")))
       {



          obj.set_create_account(name, email, password);

          // set user name/email/password
            db.DroTable();
            db.Add_User(email, password, email);
            db.Add_User(name, password, email);


            db.DropStatusTable();
            db.Add_App_Status(""+status);

          //  showtoast("Loading done  "+status);

       }
      }

      else
      {
          //showtoast("Not signed in, Email or password is incorrect");

      }
     }  };
        task.execute();  

}    


public boolean Email_Validation(String email)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");

    //String email = "xyz@xyzdomain.com";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

    boolean matchFound = matcher.matches();

    return matchFound;
}


//((((-- Convert the stream from Url to string --)))
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}//EOF AcclerometerService Class

Comment: Does the TV Box have an accelerometer ?

Comment: I dont know. because i am working remotely for some one

Answer (score 0):

Where you initialize the sensor object, you should check that it exists, and produce proper error if it doesn't:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if (accelerometer != null)
{
    // Device has Accelerometer
}
```